# Why can I put comments in some JSON files but not others?

Tags: json, comments, webstorm

My IDE (WebStorm) lets me put comments in some of my JSON files (e.g., `tsconfig.json` and `.eslintrc.json`, but balks at allowing them in others (e.g., `package.json` and `app.json`).

The former are subsequently identified as "JSON with Comments" on GitHub (even if I don't actually have comments in them).

Why can I put comments in some JSON files but not others?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By default the IDE checks for strict standard compliance, as standard JSON doesn't allow comments.

We have a set of options to relax compliance checking in **Settings | Editor | Inspections, JSON and JSON5 | Compliance with JSON standard**, and for some files the option for checking comments is off by default  (`tsconfig`, `tslint` and `eslint` configs), as corresponding tools allow comments in JSON (this is hardcoded).

If you need adding comments to certain JSON files, you can add their names to the list of patterns associated with **JSON5** file type in **Settings | Editor | File Types** - JSON5 standard allows comments

Comment: Regarding `JSON5` and comments, both `//` and `/* ... */` are supported as of 2023: https://spec.json5.org/#comments ; `PhpStorm` indicates syntax of ESLint file `.eslintrc.json` as `JSON: ESLint`.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot put comments in JSON files. JSON does not allow comments. Note that there are a couple of subtly different variants of serialization formats that are all called "JSON", but none of those allow comments:

- [The original specification by Douglas Crockford](https://json.org/).
- [ECMA-404 - *The JSON Data Interchange Syntax*](https://ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm).
- [RFC 8259 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259).

There are some slight differences between them, but they all have in common that they don't allow comments. This is by design. Quoting Douglas Crockford:

> I removed comments from JSON because I saw people were using them to hold parsing directives, a practice which would have destroyed interoperability. I know that the lack of comments makes some people sad, but it shouldn't.
>
> Suppose you are using JSON to keep configuration files, which you would like to annotate. Go ahead and insert all the comments you like. Then pipe it through JSMin before handing it to your JSON parser.

However, there *are* some serialization formats that look similar to JSON that *do* allow comments:

- [The JSON5 Data Interchange Format - JSON for Humans](https://json5.org/).
- [HOCON - Human-Optimized Config Notation](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md).
- [Hjson - a user interface for JSON](https://hjson.org/).

There are also several JSON parsing libraries that allow some styles of comments, but there is no single formal specification that covers all of them.

There is also [YAML - YAML Ain't Markup Language](https://yaml.org/), which is a superset of JSON and has comments.

> Why can I put comments in some JSON files but not others?

You cannot put comments in JSON files. But some of those files aren't JSON, they are something different which allows comments.

In particular, both TypeScript and ESLint happen to use JSON parsers that ignore comments to parse their configuration files, and some editors, IDEs, syntax highlighters, language detectors, etc. know that and will parse those files using a parser that allows comments. Although note that since there is no formal specification for JSON with comments, there is no guarantee that a comment that is accepted by TypeScript will also be accepted by ESLint, or that a comment that WebStorm thinks will be accepted by TypeScript actually will be accepted.

When in doubt, stick with formally standardized formats such as YAML, [OGDL - Ordered Graph Data Language](https://ogdl.org/), or [TOML - Tom's Obvious Minimal Language](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml).

Comment: Ah, so basically my IDE is smart enough to know that the consumers of some JSON (here ESLint and TypeScript) won't mind if there are comments. (And Github is basically flagging that these files are not standard JSON.)